# Laravel Sociallite facebook login on popup window

Tags: javascript

> Login Controller :  public function redirectToFacebook()
> {
> return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
> }
>
> ```
>  public function handleFacebookCallback()
> {
>   $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
>
>   $this->_registerOrLogin($user);
>
>   return redirect('/player/dashboard');
>
>
> }
>
> public function _registerOrLogin($data)
> {
>  $user = User::where('email', $data->email)->first();
> if ($user) {
>     $user->update([
>         'provider_token' => $data->token,
>         'provider_refresh_token' => $data->refreshToken,
>     ]);
> } else {
>     $user = User::create([
>         'username' => $data->name,
>         'first_name' => $data['given_name'],
>         'last_name' => $data['faimly_name'],
>         'email' => $data->email,
>         'role' => 'player',
>         'provider_id' => $data->id,
>         'provider_token' => $data->token,
>         'provider_refresh_token' => $data->refreshToken,
>     ]);
> }
>
> Auth::login($user);
>
> }
> ```
>
> Button To Login Facebook: LOGIN
> WITH FACEBOOK
>
> Routes used :  // Social Login Routes For Facebook
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToFacebook')->name('login.facebook');
> Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleFacebookCallback'); });
> ```
>
> 1. 
>
> > List item
>
> ---